# GUI crashes after uninstalling KDE Plama

Tags: boot

So I'm was using Ubuntu but I wanted to give KDE Plasma a try. I heard switching between desktop envirnments was pretty seamless. However, I found that I didn't really like it, so I tried removing it. I used the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove KDE-plasma-desktop
sudo apt autoremove KDE-plasma-desktop
```

However, when I rebooted, I boot to a black screen with just /dev/sad1: clean, etc(which I assume is ubuntu without the GUI, so just the terminal). From here, I found a temporary solution to use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

Which restarts the GUI and logs me in as a console user I think? But I don't know how to fix the issue permanently. Does anyone know what I foolishly deleted to cause this?

EDIT: So I found out what was wrong. It was specifically not working because removing KDE must have corrupted the gnome display manager, GDM3. I actually tried reinstalling it earlier but the didn't do anything, so I assumed it wasn't the culprit. However, when I tried installing lightdm it worked. So when I clean reinstalled the GDM3 it fixed it. I appreciate all the responses!

Comment: Maybe, this can fix the issue, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tg4fWsFPzSE&t=6s. Also, installing another de such as kde plasma is highly not recommended. It's possible that it broke the system after removing kde plasma

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Yeah I guess I incorecctly assumed that you can mix and match like android launchers, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I  think my only option is to reinstall. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: with more info, it seems like SDDM was the problem.

SDDM (default KDE login manager) is trying to load KDE and failing. You might need to disable / uninstall SDDM.

```
sudo systemctl disable sddm
# or
sudo apt remove sddm
```

---

*Leaving the original answer in case it helps others:*

If running `sudo systemctl restart gdm` works, that means you still have gdm/Gnome installed, and they are just not automatically running at boot time. You can enable them so they run on boot with this systemctl command:

`sudo systemctl enable --now gdm`

next time you log in. That will enable gdm so it always starts on boot, and start it immediately (`--now` flag).

Comment: When I try that at startup, it lets me into the GUI, but when I reboot, the same thing happens again. Something important that I just realized I omitted was that when I boot up ubuntu, like I mentioned, I get the /dev/sad1: clean message, but to get to the command line, I have to alt +control+ F#. I think that opens up a virtual desktop in the terminal, which is possibly why your solution isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `/dev/sda1: clean` message means. However, your problem could be that SDDM (default KDE login manager) is trying to load KDE and failing. You might need to disable / uninstall SDDM.

Comment: So I learned that the /dev/sd message is normally flashed upon boot but disappears immediately. So because I didn't have a working greeter I'm assuming it was stuck there. But yeah it basically fell into line with what you just mentioned, the login manager

Comment: Ok, updated the answer with new info.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what works is:

1. Booting into recovery mode using <kbd>Esc</kbd> during startup.
2. Logging in to my account using my username then password
3. `sudo apt remove lightdm`
4. `sudo apt install lightdm`, after that selecting `lightdm` in the menu showed.
5. Reboot

What I think, somehow `lightdm` got corrupted or may not be set, as a DM.
Therefore, uninstalling and installing it again works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this it means that you have tried to install KDE or any other desktop environment and didn't like it and tried to switch back to genome or you have messed with your desktop environment.

Don't worry I will help you out.

Steps:

1. Reboot your pc either by running `sudo reboot` or by manually pressing on power button.
2. Durning boot please select Ubuntu advanced options.
3. Now scroll down by pressing the down arrow from your keyboard and select recovery mode.
4. Once you're in recovery menu scroll down by pressing the down arrow from your keyboard and select dpkg repair broken packages and hit enter.
5. It will ask for to press Y. Just do it and wait until it tells you to press enter and then press enter.
6. Now scroll down to grub. Update gurb boot loader and press enter and Y if it asks you and then wait until it fixes the grub and then hit enter if it asks you do it.

(for your clarity we have fixed packages and grub by following the above steps)

7. Now you need to scroll up to resume resume normal boot and hit enter. it will take you to a terminal and it will ask you to login.
8. So login with your username and password.
9. Now enter these commands carefully and slowly.
10. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -f`  --> to update all packages.

    `sudo apt-get install lightdm`  --> to install light dm. This file may have gotten corrupted which is causing the issues. So we are fixing it first.

    If it shows a menu to choose GDN and lightdm please choose lightdm and hit enter.
11. `sudo apt-get install gdm3`

    If it shows a menu to choose GDM and lightdm please choose gdm and hit enter.
12. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

    If it show a menu to choose gdm and lightdm please choose gdm and hit enter.
13. `sudo systemctl stop lightdm`  --> we are stop lightdm so that our boot loader can't use it.
14. `sudo systemctl start gdm3` --> we are trying to start gdm3 so that our boot loader can use it.
15. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` --> choose gdm and  hit enter
16. `sudo service lightdm stop` --> trying to stop all the services so that it can't be used by the boot loader.
17. `sudo service gdm3 start`  or `sudo service gdm start`  --> it will start the services of gdm3 for boot loader.
18. `sudo reboot`
19. After rebooting please choose ubuntu and hit enter and wait it will start genome3.
    you can verify it by seeing the login page where it will use the username at the center of the screen.

if your seeing username or login at the left bottom of the screen then it means your using lightdm not genome. please stop it by using the above commands.